# What standards and best practices should I follow to write interoperable portlets or web gadgets?

Tags: interop, portlet

I am trying to design the standards and patterns for implementing portlets/web gadgets with the main goal of maximizing interoperability if those components were hosted in a Java app server framework or within an existing ASP.NET technology (SharePoint webparts), or a client side-only framework.

Is there any guidance anywhere of the parts of different portlet standards that are shared between most portal frameworks?

Is the best I can hope for is to adhere to the JSR 168 and 286 standards and hitch my wagon to Java?

Comment: Portlets have dubious portability between Java portal implementations, never mind between java and .net

Answer (score 0):

What about [WSRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_for_Remote_Portlets)?

Comment: Yes I've seen that, and it looks decent.  Although I wish MS would have baked-in support for WSRP.  Seems like they like their own technology - WebParts